# Calling a function whos name is stored in a string

Tags: string, lua, computercraft

I have a function e.g.

```
function run()
    print("hi")
end
```

I have a string called message which contains the word "run":

```
activity = message
print(activity) --returns run
```

However I am unable to use the string activity to run the function `run()`. I have tried:

```
func = loadstring(activity.."()")
func() -- I get an error on line 1 saying: attempt to call nil
```

Comment: Can you put those (partial) snippets of code into context with each other? Where is `run` in relation to `activity` in the code?

Comment: Also `_G[activity]()` is more efficient than `loadstring(activity.."()")()`

Comment: Functions (like all values) don't have names. Variables have names. It would be more correct to say that you have a global variable that references a function and you want to call the function using the name of the variable in a string.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the function run is stored in _G so the simple answer:

```
_G[message]()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function run() print("hi") end
activity = "run"
loadstring(activity.."()")()
```

This works fine as long as `loadstring` is running in the same [environment](http://www.lua.org/pil/14.html) as `run`. In other words, the `loadstring` line is equivalent to `_G[activity]()`. If the global `run` was created in some other environment, that'll evaluate to `nil`.

Given that Lua functions are first class values, just like strings, if at all possible it would be better to do this:

```
function run() print("hi") end
activity = run
activity()
```

Though if this is in a context where you're getting a string value from config file or something, that wouldn't work.